# android: stretching the surface view horizontally

Tags: android, surfaceview, stretch

I am using a media player in my android application and have set a surface view. Here is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/main_view"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</SurfaceView>
```

My problem is that, I am having blank spaces on the right and left of my video. I want IT TO BE STRETCHED HORIZONTALLY.. Can anyone advise me how I can stretch the surfaceview or my mediaplayer horizontally?
Here is the code that I am using for my mediaplayer

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
holder = mPreview.getHolder();
holder.addCallback(this);
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Please let me know if there is any problem in the xml or in the code. 
Thanks to all

Comment: in surfaceview have you tried changing android:layout_width="fill_parent"???

Answer (score 1):

try to use layout_width of surface view to fill_parent

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Comment: try it after removing android:layout_gravity="center",the tell me if it works.

Comment: I'll try it and will tell you shortly.. I actually just want it to fully stretch (only horizontally) to the size of the screen

Comment: use android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" and use android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: Sir, I have edited my question.. The above method also didn't work. Please see if I am doing anything wrong in the code.. Thanks

Comment: then use specific width as your screen like android:layout_width=480dp".I dont have any other idea.